# How has Dark Age of Camelot changed since Shrouded Isles?

Tags: dark-age-of-camelot

Have the basic mechanics significantly changed over the years or is the game fundamentally the same?

Comment: I think it has all stayed the same, except new classes and such... and frontiers added low level rvr's. Also housing was added and such. Some extra talents added aswell, in the form of Master Levels...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the two week trial and gave it a go. Mechanically most of the game is still the same or very similar. However, the process of leveling has been so significantly changed that most of the mechanics are less interesting than they had been. If you liked it, it's still there, but don't expect the challenge that was present when the game was young...don't expect a lot of exploration either.